# RGB2D Map using gmapping

Tags: slam, navigation, rgbd, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am trying to add colour information in 2d occupancy map gmapping produce.
My question is, more general, to achieve that out put where i should be looking in slam_gampping code?

Thanks in advance.

P.S My laser range finder and camera are already calibrated and i can represent any laser scan in camera pixel and extract its colour. The desired output should be colour map incorporated with the colour camera sees at that position instead of black and white map.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55255/rgb2d-map-using-gmapping/) by [Zee-Q](https://answers.ros.org/users/1806/zee-q/) on ROS Answers with karma: 235 on 2013-02-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Within the gmapping package, you'll find that there is a simple ROS wrapper around the underlying library/app. Unfortunately, if you want to "add color" to each cell, you'd have to do that within the underlying library -- and I think that would involve going as far as changing the underlying representation of what a "laser scan" is within gmapping.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0